# Where is IAC valve on 2003 Ford Ranger 6 cylinder?

Tags: ford, ranger, iac-valve

I'm working in my grandson's car.  His idle goes up and down with the A/C off. I can't figure out where the IAC is. He just bought it and we don't have manuals or diagrams yet.  Can someone help me figure out the IAC location? I want to take the old one to our parts store to make sure the replacement is the same.

Comment: I think you need 25 rep to be able to post comments.  You will get a couple votes for this question then you will be able to post comments to thank people then. I think some guys will flow to your question.  Pretty good knowledge base in here.

Comment: You should now be able to write comments.  It looks like both @paulster2 and I upvoted you.  Fly be free.

Comment: Yes. I just figured it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the 2.3L 4cyl, it should be here just behind the throttle body on the passenger side:

[image]

If the V6 (either 3.0 or 4.0), I *think* it should be right on top of the intake like it is on this V6 Escape:

[image]

If it isn't there on the V6, you should still be looking for the same shaped part. It should be on the outside of the intake near the front and is usually plainly visible.

Comment: Thank you.  I could write comments before. Your a good man.  I fixed if it

Comment: Could not write comments before

Comment: @user14094 - No worries! Stop by anytime you need a *quick fix* :o)